# should I use "end up being full of charges" or "end up full of charges" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

*When you keep charging a capacitor for a period of time, the plates will end up being full of charges* 
and 
*When you keep charging a capacitor for a period of time, the plates will end up full of charges*

Which one is the best expression, or both of them are wrong sentences? Thank you very much for your suggestions. I learn from the dictionary that **end up** can be used as end up + adj. and end up + adv./prep and end up doing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are equally correct, but **charge** is uncountable in this usage:

- **... the plates will end up being full of charge**
- **... the plates will end up full of charge**

**Charge** can countable if you are speaking of individual electrons or ions, but is more normally uncountable as you are usually speaking of the overall effect.